# Setting outlet in routerlink updates all links on site

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have a site that has several routerlinks in the header/footer of the site.

On a particular page I used outlets to create a sidebar.  Ex.

```
[routerLink]="['', { outlets: { sidebar: 'details'}}]"
```

My problem is that while the outlet works, I'm noticing every link in my header and footer are now also including the sidebar details in their url.  I would like the sidebar details to only be added to the routerLink I specify it in, and when activated, not change other urls.

I've even tried adding an outlet definition to the header links but that doesn't solve the problem.  IE:

```
[routerLink]="['/doesnt-work', { outlets: { sidebar: null}}]"
```

Since the sidebar is active in the url, it just adds it to the /doesnt-work routerlink.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Figured out the issue only occurs when the RouterModule type onSameUrlNavigation is set to 'ignore'. If it is set to reload, this is not an issue.